# Limit of product of complex functions, one of which is bounded

Tags: complex-numbers

> Suppose $g$ is a bounded complex function, in other words there exists $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|g(z)|\leq M$, for all $z$. If $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=0$ prove that $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)g(z)=0$.

This doesn't follow immediately from the properties of limits, or is there something behind the fact that the function is bounded?

Because
$$\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)g(z)=\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)\cdot\lim_{z \to z_0}g(z)=
0\cdot\lim_{z \to z_0}g(z)=0$$

Comment: Usually one will say $g$ is a bounded function.

Comment: Did not understand what you mean

Comment: You wrote: Suppose $g$ is limited complex function. Usually, it is written as: Suppose $g$ is a bounded complex function.

Comment: Your argument is right. Here a more rigourous version : Let $\epsilon > 0$. Fix $\delta > 0$ such that for $|z-z_0| < \delta$ $|f(z)| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}$. Then, $|g(z)f(z)| < M\frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon$ for $|z-z_0| < \delta$ and then $f(z)g(z) \to 0$ when $z \to z_0$.

Comment: @N.H. How can his argument be right? For him to do the very first step (arithmetic of limits) **both** limits must exist, and we don't know that about $\;g(z)\;$ !

Comment: you're right, I read it too quickly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the squeeze theorem:

$$0\le|f(z)g(z)|=|f(z)|\,|g(z)|\le |f(z)|\cdot M\xrightarrow[z\to 0]{}0\cdot M=0$$

Comment: So I can not apply the arithmetic limits directly, because I do not know about the existence of g limit?

Comment: @askazy That's correct: we cannot.